# populate the data grid form with selected categories

Tags: livecode

The stack I made is displaying categorized lines of text. I made a card to select the categories put them into a variable and populate a data grid form but the code for populating the data grid for My Categories does not work:

Here is the code for populating the form:

```
global gAllLines,gSelectedCategories,gMyCategories  
on mouseUp  
   put empty into gAllLines  
   put fld "alllines" of cd "settings_files" of stack "settingsandfiles" into gAllLines  
   put empty into gMyCategories  

   repeat for each line i in gAllLines  
      if item 2 of i is among the items of gSelectedCategories then put i & cr after gMyCategories  
   end repeat  

   set the dgText of group "mycategories_compact" to gMyCategories  

end mouseUp
```

The download link for the stack (best working so far, but still not 100% OK) is:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/Data%20grid%20Form_All%20Lines%20Categories%20Selections3.zip

Please let me know how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.
keram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have two different itemDelimiters. Your field "alllines" has tab delimited data while your gSelectedCategories has comma delimited. Try:

```
global gAllLines,gSelectedCategories,gMyCategories  
on mouseUp  
   put empty into gAllLines  
   put fld "alllines" of cd "settings_files" of stack "settingsandfiles" into gAllLines  

   put empty into gMyCategories

   replace comma with tab in gSelectedCategories
   set the itemDelimiter to tab

   repeat for each line i in gAllLines  
      if item 2 of i is among the items of gSelectedCategories then put i & cr after gMyCategories  
   end repeat  

   set the dgText of group "mycategories_compact" to gMyCategories  
end mouseUp
```

Edit

I never use dgText so I'm not sure why buy this datagrid seems to not accept dgText["firstLineContainsColumnNames"] any more. So to me the logical solution is to use dgData:

```
global gAllLines,gSelectedCategories,gMyCategories
on mouseUp

   set the dgData of group "mycategories_compact" to empty
   put empty into gMyCategories
   replace comma with tab in gSelectedCategories
   set the itemDelimiter to tab

   local tIndex = 1,tDataA
   repeat for each line i in gAllLines
      if item 2 of i is among the items of gSelectedCategories then 
         put item 1 of i into tDataA[tIndex]["Text"]
         put item 2 of i into tDataA[tIndex]["Category"]
         add 1 to tIndex
      end if
   end repeat
   set the dgData of group "mycategories_compact" to tDataA

end mouseUp
```

Comment: Thanks Monte. I changed the itemDelimiter and now gMyCategories show up properly in the msg box but when I populate the data form with it then only check boxes are visible on the right side.  Populating the same form with gAllLines instead shows all lines OK, so it's strange... Here is the link to the corrected stack:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/Data%20grid%20Form_All%20Lines%20Categories%20Selections3.zip

Comment: I added a simplified stack with the same problem - maybe it will be easier to track the errors. Categories are not displayed but all lines do, even though the data grid forms are exactly the same for both. Here is the link for the test stack: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99863601/TextLine%20Categories.zip

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at your stack, but the handler works fine as far as it goes. That is, the global variable "gSelectedCategories" is loaded if one of the checkbox buttons has one of the words you are checking for in its name, What are you not seeing?

Craig Newman

Comment: If I select one of the check boxes of the group and click on the Apply button in the Code Editor then I'm getting an error for this line: **if the hilite of it then**, saying: **group "grpSelectCategories": execution error at line n/a (Object: object does not have this property)**. Then of course the rest - populating the data grid - does not work either.

Comment: Hi Craig, I managed to make corrections so that the selection of categories is working but populating the form does not work (see the code above and the new download link).